# BackButton quit the application

Tags: android, android-manifest, back-button

I'm experiencing a trouble on my app, my backButton quit the application. 
My application is a SyncService, everything seems to be great in the Manifest, i check for one day with no response...

I already check if the launchmode change something, i test the 4 and nothing append...
If someone can have a look on the manifest, it would be great :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.smile.android.ldapsync" android:versionCode="12" android:versionName="1.5">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /><application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true" android:enabled="true" android:persistent="true">
        <service android:name="com.smile.android.ldapsync.authenticator.LDAPAuthenticationService" android:exported="true" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.smile.android.ldapsync.syncadapter.SyncService" android:exported="true" android:debuggable="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>
        <activity android:name="com.smile.android.ldapsync.authenticator.LDAPAuthenticatorActivity" android:label="@string/ui_activity_title" android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
                <!--
                No intent-filter here! This activity is only ever launched by
                someone who explicitly knows the class name
            -->
        </activity>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5" />
</manifest>
```

Thank you ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you press back button while on the "main" activity (the first one you launched aka the bottom of your activity stack) the OS understand this as "the user is done and won't be back anytime soon" opposed as "home" button which is understood as "maybe the user wants to check something else before resuming the app"

So, if you DO NOT want your app to "terminate" (an android app terminates only when the OS kills it, otherwise it will lurk in memory until recalled) you need to override the back button pressed callback

```
public void onBackPressed()
```

which the api doc describes as:

"Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want."

You might just ignore the event and absorb it like timo schloesser suggested or you can do whatever is most appropriated (like, launching another activity or killing services before leaving the screen)

EDIT: you might also want to check the "moveTaskToBack" method inherited from Activity class. I have never used it but it might be useful to your problem.

Comment: this is the answer you are looking for.. Also just so you know onBackPressed is supported for 2.0 forward.. So if you want to support 1.6, you should use onKeyDown method and take action only for back button pressed

Answer (score 4):

Did you tried overriding onBackPressed ?

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
       return;
}
```