# how to disable the backbutton and show some other layout that shows resume and quit

Tags: android, layout, back-button

i am new to android programming. in my application if i press a backbutton or from phone back key it is coming out of application directly with out asking me to quit or resume again .

i was thinking that may be i should call a intent and set up another class and also set xml file for that class or how to do this .actually i had seen this in some game where the back button is used to disable and show some resume and quit button on it .please help me do this .it will be great help

Thank you,
maddy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this code :

```
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, Next.class);
          this.startActivity(intent);
          //this.finish();
      }
      return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

see the comments on [over-riding the onBackPressed button](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8213603/64253)

Comment: well i have override the onBackPressed method .i that shall i call an Intent or how to achive this .i need to show a Resume and quit button